# How can I use JavaScript to add CSS styles to a list element when clicked, but remove it when another li item is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hubspot, hubspot-crm

I have JavaScript to make an li element bold and underlined when clicked as part of a category selector in a sidebar.

The code is here:

```
  $('li').click(function(e){
    $(this).css('font-weight','bold');
  $(this).css('text-decoration','underline');
})
```

I'm using Hubspot and the code for the sidebar where someone can manually set a category name and then it's applied to the  list element for sorting purposes:

```
<ul class="category-sidebar">
        {% for item in module.poll_sidebar_categories %}
        <li class="{{ item.poll_sidebar_category }}">{{ item.poll_sidebar_category }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
```

I can add more code for background as needed but the sidebar appears like so:
[image]

The only problem is this code persists even when I click other options (like "all", or show category "Retention", etc). How can I have it so the css unapplies once a different li item is clicked and then the styles are applied to the new li item only?

I've tried to change to a href or add it within the li tags but it doesn't work with the other JS so I wanted to see if this was possible as list items

Comment: Rather than setting CSS properties on the individual DOM object, why don't  you just add a CSS class to that element? Then, every time a new thing is clicked, you can remove that class from any existing DOM elements and add it to the one that was just clicked.

Comment: @Josh thanks. So you are saying to have a "non clicked" css and then "clicked" css and then use JS to toggle between the 2? Is there a good example of this to reference?

Comment: Correct. When the user clicks on a clickable `<li>`, get all elements with some "clicked" class name, remove that class from each element (https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/). Then add the "clicked" class to the element that was just clicked (https://api.jquery.com/addclass/).

Answer (score 1):

```
var ul = document.getElementsByClassName("category-sidebar");
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.classList.add("[your_new_category]");
li.innerHTML = "your_new_category"
ul.appendChild(li);
```

you'll have to create and then add javascript elements to parent nodes.

Lets first get reference to our object by its classname
create new li element in the dom
set classname next, I am assuming you have your new category name in your js
append that newly created li to our ul element from the first line.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. Should I use the Hubl category code in place of "your_new_category"? Or how would that work?

Comment: that is correct, you can use your newly generated category code instead of "your_new_category".